# Bone animation doesnt apply when exporting model from blender to unity in humanoid form

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender

I Have .Fbx File which has animation file when i play it as Generic animation type it seems to be like

[image: this]

But when i change it to humanoid to target the animation file as humanoid,some bones rotation changed and it seems to be like

[image]

And if there is another way to get humaniod animation files when it is generic what is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by remapping the right arm joints